# prevent resizing with option key

Tags: keyboard, window-manager

**Hardware:** Macbook Pro 2017 (15")

**OS:** MacBook Mojave 10.14.6

While using iTerm, I noticed, I could not use `alt`/`option` commands with direction keys as I would on my Macbook Pro 2015. This prevents me from navigating around certain CLI utilities. Instead, my iTerm window gets resized as shown below using `option`+`left` and `option`+`right`. I noticed this is how all application windows behave and not just iTerm. How may I stop this behavior?

**Aside:** Another weird thing I've noticed on this newer macbook is that `cmd` + `left` and `cmd` + `right` do not work as `Home` and `End` buttons anymore. I now have to use `ctrl` + `a` and `ctrl` + `e`.

[image: iTerm resize happening with option button]

Comment: This is not standard macOS behaviour, nor can this be enabled in macOS itself. Check what third-party apps have system-wide access to window manipulation in System Preferences → Security & Privacy → Privacy → Accessibility — try disabling suspect apps and attempting the shortcut again.

Comment: Suspicious apps I have include Spectacle and Karabiner

Comment: Thanks for helping me narrow it down. It turned out this was all being caused by Slate. Maybe add your comment as an answer so I can upvote it?

Comment: Glad you've got it sorted, I've added an answer!

Comment: For anyone else that may experience this with Slate, here's another post that addresses it https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/133131/slate-window-manager-disrupts-text-manipulation/133155#133155

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is not standard macOS functionality, neither default nor optional, this is either functionality added by you (or someone acting as administrator) or a third-party app.

You can check what third-party apps have system-wide access to window manipulation in System Preferences → Security & Privacy → Privacy → Accessibility. One by one, try disabling suspect apps and attempting the shortcut again.

When you've narrowed down the specific app, you can either disable the app or research the possibility of changing/disabling the offending shortcut.